# Passing a Jquery array of objects into a php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array in jQuery that I am trying to convert to a PHP array by using Post:

```
$.post("http://www.samepage.com", {final_slip: JSON.stringify(final_slip)});
```

When I pass this dynamically created array "final_slip" into it :

```
[final_bet_game { final_user_id="1",  final_game_id="1",  final_game_type="spread_2",final_price="10", final_odds="1.8"},  final_bet_game { final_user_id="2",  final_game_id="3",  final_game_type="spread_2",final_price="1", final_odds="2.8"},  final_bet_game { final_user_id="3",  final_game_id="14",  final_game_type="spread_32",final_price="140", final_odds="1.8"},  final_bet_game { final_user_id="4",  final_game_id="1",  final_game_type="spread_2",final_price="10", final_odds="2.8"}, ]
```

I get this php outputted :

```
$data =  $_POST['final_slip'];
print_r ( $data);

[{\"final_user_id\":\"1\",\"final_game_id\":\"1\",\"final_game_type\":\"spread_2\",\"final_price\":\"211\",\"final_odds\":\"1.8\"},{\"final_user_id\":\"1\",\"final_game_id\":\"2\",\"final_game_type\":\"spread_2\",\"final_price\":\"212\",\"final_odds\":\"1.8\"},{\"final_user_id\":\"1\",\"final_game_id\":\"parlay\",\"final_game_type\":\"\",\"final_price\":\"021\",\"final_odds\":\"\"}]
```

I tried to use the json_decod, but Im not getting any results. How can I get this to a usable php array? Would I be better off using ajax?

Comment: You're already using AJAX. `$.post()` is a jQuery shorthand AJAX method.

Comment: that's totally invalid json. what exactly is in final_slip before you stringify it?

Comment: Ok how can I decode this string that is outbputed?

Comment: You cannot, until you create valid JSON.

Comment: The final_slip is the second code block in my question.

Comment: Ok I will turn my attention to converting this array I have into json first.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $.post("http://www.samepage.com", {myJsonString: JSON.stringify(myJsonString)});
> ```
>
> But when I then try to access it in PHP I am not seeing any results.

And *that* tells you that you have another problem - *PHP is not reporting errors*. You want to [turn `error_reporting` on](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

In this case the likely cause is that your data is arriving into the `$_POST` array, and `$myJsonString` is not defined ([automatic definition of parameters has been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) since PHP 5.3.0, and no longer available since PHP 5.4.0).

You should either do

```
if (array_key_exists('myJsonString', $_POST)) {
    $myJsonString = $_POST['myJsonString'];
} else {
    die("myJsonString not in _POST");
}
```

or try straight

```
$result = json_decode($_POST['myJsonString'], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the backslashes in the outout needed to be stripped out:

```
  $result = $_POST['json_string'];  
  $test =  urldecode(str_replace("\\","",$result));  
  $test2 = (json_decode($test,true));
  print_r($test2);
```